# VLC does not show any text at all, not only subtitles

Tags: video, vlc, subtitle

I have installed yesterday Ubuntu 16.04 on my new laptop, and I have an annoying problem: VLC won't show subtitles.

Not only that, it doesn't even show the title of the video file, despite the option being checked in Tools > Preferences > Subtitles/OSD.

I have tried with both external .srt files and subtitles contained in the video file, but no text is showing at any time.
The built-in video player by Ubuntu reads and displays the subtitles without any problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using another thread about VLC subtitles ([Ubuntu VLC subtitles blurry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248192/ubuntu-vlc-subtitles-blurry?rq=1)) I was able to solve myself the problem:

One has to go under Tools > Preferences > Video and and change the output field from **Default** to **x11 video output (XCB)**.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had the same issue and you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on ubuntu 20.04. I solved it by installing vlc via apt instead of snap. I guess snap install cause some problems regarding file read permissions.